# TSQL Insert Into Table From * delimited field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with one column containing millions of rows of asterisk delimited values.

I have been trying a straightforward insert statement that would be fast. Below is a pseudo code of what I tried

Test Table contents of the [cds] field:

```
bobo11*bobo12*bobo13
bobo21*bobo22*bobo23
bobo31*bobo32*bobo33
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable2
(boboA,boboB,boboC)
SELECT '''' + REPLACE(cds,'*','''' + ',' + '''') + '''' FROM Test Table
```

The trouble is that even though I do have the correct number of columns, 
the statement above is not recognized and comes back with the error message:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually parse out the values.  With the values that you have, you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable2(boboA, boboB, boboC)
    select left(cds, 6), substring(cds, 8, 6), right(cds, 6)
    from TestTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build dynamic columns list in the static query. You have to split the column values and insert them. You can try the following query instead

```
INSERT INTO TestTable2
(boboA,boboB,boboC)
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(cds,'*','.'),3)
      ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(cds,'*','.'),2)
      ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(cds,'*','.'),1)
FROM TestTable
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. Yeah, that is a problem as I am trying to improve speed of the import. I am already parsing these values in a separate procedure. The actual data is pretty wide with over 50 columns in a table and I'm running at about 300,000 records per day. With this speed the data import will take over a year :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Small example to create dynamic sql with XML PATH

```
DECLARE 
    @sql nvarchar(max) ;

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO TestTable2(boboA,boboB,boboC)VALUES' + (
select
'('''+REPLACE(A,'*',''',''')+'''),'
from Test
FOR XML PATH(''));

SET @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql,1,LEN(@sql)-1);

print @sql
```